# Different function onchange event in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, textbox, dom-events, onchange

I have three textbox in aspx form with `onchange` event function:

```
 <asp:textbox runat="server" id="txt1" onchange="f1();" />
 <asp:textbox runat="server" id="txt2" onchange="f1();" />
 <asp:textbox runat="server" id="sum" onchange="sum();" />


    function f1(){
    //change sum.text
    sum.text='125';
    }
```

When txt1.text changed and txt2 get focus, `f1()` fires for it without erasing `sum()` or `f1()` again.
When txt2.text changed and sum get focus, `f1()` fires for it and `sum()` fires too.
In IE this scenario happens, but in Firefox it does normally; why?

Comment: Try to reword and reformat your question. I have absolutely no idea what behavior you encounter in IE and what behavior you expect.

Comment: Have you tried changing `sum.text='125'` to `document.getElementById('sum').text = '125';` ? Did it help?

Comment: Tell us what you are actually trying to do

Comment: document.getElementById("sum").value=125;

Comment: Are you sure that `sum` is only bound to `onchange` or #sum? I'm quite sure it will not fire when moving focus from #txt2 to #sum, not even in IE.